# .find() method jquery object parameter

Tags: jquery

Docs: https://api.jquery.com/find/

> **As of jQuery 1.6**, we can also filter the selection with a given jQuery collection or element.

This **will** work as intended:

```
var attacks = "#incomings_table tr:not(:first,:last)";
    $(".paged-nav-item").each(function(){
        $.get(this.href,function(data){
            $("#incomings_table").find("tr:last").before($(data).find(attacks));
        },"html");
     });
```

The following **won't** insert anything before the specified element:

```
var attacks = $("#incomings_table tr:not(:first,:last)");
    $(".paged-nav-item").each(function(){
        $.get(this.href,function(data){
            $("#incomings_table").find("tr:last").before($(data).find(attacks));
        },"html");
    });
```

I'm trying to use a Jquery object as a variable for different tasks using the same selector.

Neither of these codes will give an error on the console, and both will be executed, it's just that the latter fails to perform the `.before()` method because it's using a Jquery object instead of a string.

I've already seen `.before()`'s docs and it accepts a Jquery object, as you can see in the code at `$(data)`. so I can only assume it's from the `.find()` method.

I'm using **Jquery 1.9.1**. What's the problem?

Comment: `$("#incomings_table tr:not(:first,:last)");` caches the element object currently present in DOM
. And I suspect you are dealing with multiple elements with ID incomings_table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$("#incomings_table tr:not(:first,:last)")` will find the elements that presently in the dom. But it's not there at that time so it will be null.So you should use `"#incomings_table tr:not(:first,:last)"`.

```js
var data = '<div>' + '<div class="b">' +
  +'hi' + '</div>' + '</div>',
  $sel = $('.b');

console.log('dom', $('#a').find($sel));
console.log('dom', $(data).find($sel));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="a">
  <div class="b">
    hi
  </div>
</div>
```

Consider the above example that it will only find out the `dom` element.

REF : https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/jquery-object/

Comment: hmm, if that were to be true then why isn't any `tr` element being repeatedly added to the `#incomings_table` , since I already have those elements in my page to be cached at the time I declare the variable?

Comment: The cached item is not the element present in `data`

Comment: ah, that makes sense. So I should set the variable as a string, and then call it with `$(attacks)` , and it should work?

Comment: nope, it can only select element that presently in `dom`

Comment: Yes, but if I use a string to set the variable like in my first example, I should be able to make the `.before()` method get `$(data).find($(attacks)` , because I've set the variable as a string, and a string doesn't cache anything.

Comment: while using `#incomings_table` it will search for that in `data` . But in case `$("#incomings_table')` , it will check that any of that cached object is inside in it.

Comment: exactly, what I'm saying is to simply call the string variable with $() inside the .before() parameter.

Comment: Yes. But to only call it on the .before() method.

Comment: It will ad the dom element , not from the `data`

Comment: Your example doesn't address my original problem though. The data object exists in my code and it also has the same valid selectors. What it doesn't have, is the exact `tr` elements in the given jquery object. My last question would be, Is a jquery object defined by all its descendants aswell, or just by the selector itself? Cause if it is, it would explain everything.